# Py_BuildValue segmentation fault

Tags: python, c, cpython

I am trying to run a simple python code from a C program but I get a segmentation fault at the line `pArgs = Py_BuildValue("s",(char*)"Greg");`

Here is the python code I want to run:

```
def main(person):
    return "What's up " + person;
```

Here is my C program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Python.h>

void main(void) {
        Py_Initialize();
        PyObject *pName, *pModule, *pFunc, *pArgs, *pValue;
        pName = PyUnicode_FromString((char*)"main");
        pModule = PyImport_Import(pName);
        pFunc = PyObject_GetAttrString(pModule, (char*)"main");
        pArgs = Py_BuildValue("s",(char*)"Greg"); 
        pValue = PyObject_CallObject(pFunc, pArgs);                   
        Py_Finalize();
        return;
}
```

I am working on Ubuntu 20.4

The python code launched from Idle works and the files are in the same directory the name of the python file is main.py

Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: To rule out other possible issues, you should be checking the return values of all the C API calls for NULL, in case something went wrong. A crash in Py_BuildValue could be the result of memory corruption that occurred earlier.

Comment: It should be very easy to debug this by running in a debugger. On which line does the segfault occur? As others have pointed out, any one of these calls could fail, since you never check the return values. For example, if `pModule == NULL`, then the next call getting an attribute will fault.

Comment: Also, I don't believe `PyImport_Import` uses the current directory by default (I could be wrong). If so, then `main.py` won't be importable without adding the current directory to `PYTHONPATH`.

Comment: Hi,
I started the code step by step with GDB and pModule returns NULL. I tried to fix this by adding the line `PySys_SetPath(L".");`  after the line `Py_Initialize();` but I get the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pArgs` must be a tuple.  Add parentheses to the format string:

```py
pArgs = Py_BuildValue("(s)",(char*)"Greg");
```

I didn't get a segmentation fault but a clear error message, so perhaps you have a build issue as well.

```
TypeError: argument list must be a tuple
```

Comment: Hi,
Thank you for your help. I added the parentheses but still get the error.
I compile my program with the following line:`gcc -g -o test test.c -I/usr/include/python3.8 -lpython3.8`  . I have no warning or error that goes back after that.

Comment: @Tears4fears That looks right to me but I'm on Windows and using the Microsoft compiler so can't verify.  Add some error checking or use a debugger to see where it crashes.  The code shown works for me after using `"(s)"`.

Comment: @Tears4Fears `Py_BuildValue` itself doesn't have much to go wrong.  The syntax of the line is correct.  Are you sure the crash is on that specific line?

Answer (score 0):

As you told me I replaced `pArgs = Py_BuildValue("s",(char*)"Greg");`

by  `pArgs = Py_BuildValue("(s)",(char *)"137912500");`.

As you told me, I was in the wrong directory so I added `PySys_SetPath(L".");`.

Here is my corrected C code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Python.h>

void main(void) {
        Py_Initialize();
        PyObject *pName,*pName2, *pModule, *pFunc, *pArgs, *pValue;
        PySys_SetPath(L".");
        pName = PyUnicode_FromString((char*)"main");
        pModule = PyImport_Import(pName);
        pFunc = PyObject_GetAttrString(pModule, (char*)"main");
        pArgs = Py_BuildValue("(s)",(char *)"137912500");
        pValue = PyObject_CallObject(pFunc, pArgs);                  
        Py_Finalize();                                               
        return;
}
```

Thank you again for your help.